# Replace uppercase with lowercase letters

Tags: sublimetext

I'm trying to replace uppercase letters with corresponding lowercase letters using regex.
So that

```
EarTH:   1,
MerCury: 0.2408467,
venuS:   0.61519726,
```

becomes

```
earth:   1,
mercury: 0.2408467,
venus:   0.61519726,
```

in Sublime Text. How can I downcase letters only in words that contain both lower and uppercase letters? So that it affects `venUs` and not `VENUS`.

Answer (score 623, accepted):

You may:

Find: `(\w)`
Replace With: `\L$1`

Or select the text, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: super. very useful.  Could you please point to some resource that lists transformations like '\L' ?

Comment: Sublime uses Boost for its RegEx support, these are the docs for the format strings like \L: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/perl_format.html

Comment: And in IntelliJ

Comment: Note: To go to uppercase, you'll need `\U`

Comment: Is it possible to only lowercase a single parameter in a replacement? For instance, `$1.\L$2($3)` to lowercase `$2` while not making `$3` lowercase?

Comment: To only lowercase a single parameter, put \E after it to end the lowercase section:  `$1\L$2\E$3`

Comment: @Patrick IntelliJ is the same syntax. Cmd/Ctrl-R for find/replace. Click the little `.*` icon to turn on regex. `$1` for the first matching group. `$2` for the second ... `$n` for the nth. You use the dollar syntax in the results. So the find would be `(\w)` the replace would be `\L$1`.

Comment: Just a note .NET Regex class doesn't honor replace tags like  \L, \U, \E etc.

Comment: If anyone is here using VS Code, `\L$1` works there too!

Comment: This doesn't work in Visual Studio's Find & Replace.

Comment: to lower a single letter you can also use lower case 'L' `\l$1` instead of `\L$1\E`

Answer (score 214):

I figured this might come in handy for others as well :

find:

- `([A-Z])(.*)`

replace:

- `\L$1$2` --> will convert all letters in `$1` and `$2` to lowercase
  **BUT**
- `\l$1$2` --> will only convert the first letter of `$1` to lowercase and leave everything else as is

The same goes for uppercase with `\U` and `\u`

Comment: `\l$1$2` would only make the whole `$1` in lower case in this case here, because `$i` contains only one letter. `\l` => first following letter to lower case and `\u` => first following letter to upper case. Where `\U` and `\I` doing it to all following letters.

Comment: Note that `\E` terminates a `\L` or `\U` sequence.

Answer (score 122):

Before searching with regex like `[A-Z]`, you should **press the case sensitive button** (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) (as [leemour nicely suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742076/regex-replace-uppercase-with-lowercase-letters#comment31081326_20742304) to be edited in the accepted answer). Just to be clear, I'm leaving a few other examples:

1. **[Capitalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization) words**

- Find: `(\s)([a-z])` (`\s` also matches new lines, i.e. "venuS" => "VenuS")
- Replace: `$1\u$2`

2. **Uncapitalize words**

- Find: `(\s)([A-Z])`
- Replace: `$1\l$2`

3. **Remove [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)** (e.g. cAmelCAse => camelcAse => camelcase)

- Find: `([a-z])([A-Z])`
- Replace: `$1\l$2`

4. **Lowercase letters within words** (e.g. LowerCASe => Lowercase)

- Find: `(\w)([A-Z]+)`
- Replace: `$1\L$2`
- Alternate Replace: `\L$0`

5. **Uppercase letters within words** (e.g. upperCASe => uPPERCASE)

- Find: `(\w)([A-Z]+)`
- Replace: `$1\U$2`

6. **Uppercase previous** (e.g. upperCase => UPPERCase)

- Find: `(\w+)([A-Z])`
- Replace: `\U$1$2`

7. **Lowercase previous** (e.g. LOWERCase => lowerCase)

- Find: `(\w+)([A-Z])`
- Replace: `\L$1$2`

8. **Uppercase the rest** (e.g. upperCase => upperCASE)

- Find: `([A-Z])(\w+)`
- Replace: `$1\U$2`

9. **Lowercase the rest** (e.g. lOWERCASE => lOwercase)

- Find: `([A-Z])(\w+)`
- Replace: `$1\L$2`

10. **Shift-right-uppercase** (e.g. Case => cAse => caSe => casE)

- Find: `([a-z\s])([A-Z])(\w)`
- Replace: `$1\l$2\u$3`

11. **Shift-left-uppercase** (e.g. CasE => CaSe => CAse => Case)

- Find: `(\w)([A-Z])([a-z\s])`
- Replace: `\u$1\l$2$3`

Regarding the question (match **words with at least one uppercase and one lowercase letter** and make them lowercase), [leemour's comment-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742076/regex-replace-uppercase-with-lowercase-letters#comment31081326_20742304) is the **right answer**. Just to clarify, if there is only one group to replace, you can just use `?:` in the inner groups (i.e. [non capture groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group)) or avoid creating them at all:

- Find: `((?:[a-z][A-Z]+)|(?:[A-Z]+[a-z]))` OR `([a-z][A-Z]+|[A-Z]+[a-z])`
- Replace: `\L$1`

### 2016-06-23 Edit

[Tyler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4695615/tyler-b-long) suggested by editing this answer an alternate find expression for #4:

- `(\B)([A-Z]+)`

According to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html), `\B` will look for a character that is not at the word's boundary (i.e. not at the beginning and not at the end). You can use the *Replace All* button and it does the exact same thing as if you had `(\w)([A-Z]+)` as the find expression.

However, the downside of `\B` is that it does not allow single replacements, perhaps due to the *find*'s "not boundary" restriction (please do edit this if you know the exact reason).

### 2023-08-24 Edit

To end changing the letter case, use `\E`

- replace: `$1\L$2\E$3`  (e.g. `(ABC)(ABC)(ABC)` => `ABCabcABC`)

Answer (score 5):

- **FIND:** `(\u)`
- **REPLACE:** `\L$1$2`

Operation confirmed in Notepad++.

Do not forget to check the "Match case" box.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

- Find: `([A-Z])([A-Z]+)\b`
- Replace: `$1\L$2`

Make sure case sensitivity is on (Alt + C)

Comment: That doesn't work. It matches 2+ uppercase letters. But I understand that `\L` is for lowercase. I updated the question.

Answer (score 4):

Regular expression

**Find**:`\w+`

**Replace**:`\L$0`

> Sublime Text uses the Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE)
>   engine from the Boost library to power regular expressions in search
>   panels.

`\L` Converts everything up  to lowercase

`$0` Capture groups

Answer (score 2):

In BBEdit works this (ex.: changing the ID values to lowercase):

Search any value: `<a id="(?P<x>.*?)"></a>`
Replace with the same in lowercase: `<a id="\L\P<x>\E"></a>`

Was: `<a id="VALUE"></a>`
Became: `<a id="value"></a>`

Answer (score 2):

To convert **`snake_case`** words with some additional fields starting with `_`:

EXAMPLE:

```
_id
user_name
```

to

```
id
userName
```

Use first:

- **FIND**: (\w)_(\w)
- **REPLACE**: $1\U$2

Then, just replace `"_"` to `""` (Blank space)