# How to switch text case in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How does one switch the case of highlighted text in Visual Studio Code? VS allows this via CTRL+SHIFT+U and CTRL+U.

Is there a command binding that I can set up to do this, or is it by default some other key combination?

Comment: I can't find any relevant shortcuts in key bindings. Probably this function is not supported in the current version.

Comment: Update: it is supported now. Go to File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts and search for "Transform".

Comment: Any way to toggle letter?

Comment: I configure the key as `shift + L` and `shift + U`.

Comment: @Eric I wonder how you type an uppercase L or U after these keys were defined.,.

Comment: @theking2 you can override them.

Answer (score 490):

Echoing [justanotherdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2480940/justanotherdev)'s comment:

Mind-blowing and useful:

1. Command Palette: `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `p` (Mac: `CMD` + `SHIFT` + `p`)
2. type `>transform` pick upper/lower case and press enter

[image]

Comment: It's possible to configure keybindings for this commands on File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

Comment: pycharm uses the same command CTRL+SHIFT+ "u" to toggle.
why create 2 shortcuts when one could be used? 
i realize this is not an answer, just a comment.

Comment: sometimes you have "Mixed  casing Text" that you want to go directly to "ALL UPPERCASE" or "all lowercase", so transforming to uppercase and transforming to lowercase separately make more sense.

Comment: very useful particularly with multiple selections

Comment: How to combine transform with "rename" meaning it automatically updates the same variables (F2).

Answer (score 102):

Quoted from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184509/visual-studio-code-make-selected-block-of-text-uppercase?rq=1):

> The question is about how to make CTRL+SHIFT+U work in Visual Studio
> Code. Here is how to do it. (Version 1.8.1 or above). You can also choose a different key combination.
>
> **File-> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts.**
>
> An editor will appear with `keybindings.json` file. Place the following
> JSON in there and save.
>
> ```
> [
>  {
>     "key": "ctrl+shift+u",
>     "command": "editor.action.transformToUppercase",
>     "when": "editorTextFocus"
>  },
>  {
>     "key": "ctrl+shift+l",
>     "command": "editor.action.transformToLowercase",
>     "when": "editorTextFocus"
>  }
> ]
> ```
>
> Now CTRL+SHIFT+U will capitalise selected text, even if multi line. In
> the same way, CTRL+SHIFT+L will make selected text lowercase.
>
> These commands are built into VS Code, and no extensions are required
> to make them work.

UPDATE:
To open the JSON editor, click this icon in the top right corner:

[image]

Comment: I went for `cmd+shift+u` and `cmd+shift+l` on macOS. Feels just right.

Comment: For Linux ctrl+shift+u is not working, so instead use 
key ctrl+u for uppercase & ctrl+l for lowercase

Comment: Is it possible to have one keyboard shortcut cycle through each option instead of having separate keyboard shortcuts for each one? That is, can I set it up so that hitting `shift+f3` changes it ToUppercase, hitting `shift+f3` changes it ToLowercase, hitting it again changes it ToSnakecase, and hitting it again changes it ToTitlecase?

Comment: To find this hidden JSON editor with VS Code 1.72.2 (Sept. 2022) or later, click on the blank page icon with the curved arrow, which points to that blank page. It's in the upper right hand corner after using File-> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts. Look for the 3 dots icon. It's the 1st icon on the left, before the split pane icon. The alt text says "Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)". That will open the keybindings.json file. Saving that file will automatically enable the changes, without relaunching VS Code.

Comment: Thank you my good sir, this makes my life so much easier

Comment: Re: "An editor will appear with `keybindings.json file`": no, it won't. Version 1.75.1.

Comment: @Clomp I cannot find "Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)". Help. UPD: found.

Answer (score 76):

I've written a Visual Studio Code extension for changing case (not only upper case, many other options): https://github.com/wmaurer/vscode-change-case

To map the upper case command to a keybinding (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd>), click *File -> Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts*, and insert the following into the json config:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+t u",
  "command": "extension.changeCase.upper",
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

**EDIT:**

With the November 2016 [(release notes)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates#_sublime-text-compatibility) update of VSCode, there is built-in support for converting to upper case and lower case via the commands `editor.action.transformToUppercase` and `editor.action.transformToLowercase`. These don't have default keybindings.

The [change-case](https://github.com/wmaurer/vscode-change-case) extension is still useful for other text transformations, e.g. camelCase, PascalCase, snake-case, etc.

Comment: the "ctrl+t u" didn't work for me on the mac version. I used "ctrl+u" instead as it's not mapped by default to any action.

Comment: For lazy people: select the text, ctrl + p, type `>transform` pick lower or upper case then press enter

Comment: An addendum to @justanotherdev's comment: it's possible to configure keybindings for this commands on File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

Comment: Isn't there a way to have these options show up in the right click menu (the way Nptepad++ does) ?

Comment: @justanotherdev to be honest, that's a faster process for me though, plus it is already baked in and no need for 'Yet Another Extension'

Answer (score 21):

Use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette prompt.

In the command, palette start typing the text casing you wish to transform e.g lowercase or uppercase then select the appropriate option that you are presented as shown in the figure below.
[image]

Answer (score 18):

To have in ***Visual Studio Code*** what you can do in ***Sublime Text***  ( <kbd>CTRL+K CTRL+U</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL+K CTRL+L</kbd> ) you could do this:

- Open "*Keyboard Shortcuts*" with click on "***File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts***"
- Click on "***keybindings.json***" link which appears under "*Search keybindings*" field
- Between the `[]` brackets add:

  ```
  {
      "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+u",
      "command": "editor.action.transformToUppercase",
      "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
      "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+l",
      "command": "editor.action.transformToLowercase",
      "when": "editorTextFocus"
  }
  ```
- Save and close "***keybindings.json***"

---

***Another way:***
Microsoft released ***"Sublime Text Keymap and Settings Importer"***, an extension which imports keybindings and settings from Sublime Text to VS Code.
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.sublime-keybindings

Comment: I don't know if it's new, but when I did this all I had to do was put "uppercase" in the search box that appeared, then click a '+' to add a new mapping.
Repeat with "lowercase" to cover the other direction and I was all set.

Comment: ctrl+k ctrl+u is usually reserved for uncomment... i've set mine to alt+k alt+u and alt+k alt+l.

Answer (score 15):

For those who fear to mess anything up in your vscode json settings this is pretty easy to follow.

1. Open **`"File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts"`**
   or **`"Code -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts"`** for Mac Users
2. In the search bar type **`transform`**.
3. By default you will not have anything under **`Keybinding`**. Now double-click on **`Transform to Lowercase`** or **`Transform to Uppercase`**.
4. Press your desired combination of keys to set your keybinding. In this case if copying off of Sublime i will press **`ctrl+shift+u`** for uppercase or **`ctrl+shift+l`** for lowercase.
5. Press **`Enter`** on your keyboard to save and exit. Do same for the other option.
6. Enjoy `KEYBINDING`

Answer (score 14):

Now an uppercase and lowercase switch can be done simultaneously in the selected strings via a regular expression replacement (regex, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>), according to [v1.47.3 June 2020 release](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_47#_editor):

[image: Replacing different text cases in one selection]

This is done through 4 ["Single character" character classes (Perl documentation)](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax._quot_single_character_quot__character_classes_), namely, for **the matched group following it**:

- **\l** <=> `[[:lower:]]`: first character becomes lowercase
- **\u** <=> `[[:upper:]]`: first character becomes uppercase
- **\L** <=> `[^[:lower:]]`: all characters become lowercase
- **\U** <=> `[^[:upper:]]`: all characters become uppercase

`$0` matches all selected groups, while `$1` matches the 1st group, `$2` the 2nd one, etc.

Hit **the Match Case button** at the left of the search bar (or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>) and, borrowing some examples from an [old Sublime Text answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33351224/6225838), now this is possible:

1. **[Capitalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization) words**

- Find: `(\s)([a-z])` (`\s` matches spaces and new lines, i.e. " venuS" => " VenuS")
- Replace: `$1\u$2`

2. **Uncapitalize words**

- Find: `(\s)([A-Z])`
- Replace: `$1\l$2`

3. **Remove a single [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)** (e.g. cAmelCAse => camelcAse => camelcase)

- Find: `([a-z])([A-Z])`
- Replace: `$1\l$2`

4. **Lowercase all from an uppercase letter within words** (e.g. LowerCASe => Lowercase)

- Find: `(\w)([A-Z]+)`
- Replace: `$1\L$2`
- Alternate Replace: `\L$0`

5. **Uppercase all from a lowercase letter within words** (e.g. upperCASe => uPPERCASE)

- Find: `(\w)([A-Z]+)`
- Replace: `$1\U$2`

6. **Uppercase previous** (e.g. upperCase => UPPERCase)

- Find: `(\w+)([A-Z])`
- Replace: `\U$1$2`

7. **Lowercase previous** (e.g. LOWERCase => lowerCase)

- Find: `(\w+)([A-Z])`
- Replace: `\L$1$2`

8. **Uppercase the rest** (e.g. upperCase => upperCASE)

- Find: `([A-Z])(\w+)`
- Replace: `$1\U$2`

9. **Lowercase the rest** (e.g. lOWERCASE => lOwercase)

- Find: `([A-Z])(\w+)`
- Replace: `$1\L$2`

10. **Shift-right-uppercase** (e.g. Case => cAse => caSe => casE)

- Find: `([a-z\s])([A-Z])(\w)`
- Replace: `$1\l$2\u$3`

11. **Shift-left-uppercase** (e.g. CasE => CaSe => CAse => Case)

- Find: `(\w)([A-Z])([a-z\s])`
- Replace: `\u$1\l$2$3`

Comment: What a wonderful thing! This answer is the best! Reminds me of DreamWeaver 8 where I would revamp entire sites with regex - especially bloated MS stuff. Anyway, this was super useful in scripting DB2-to-(lowercase)Postgres SQL change-over.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a feature currently missing right now.

I noticed when I was making a guide for the keyboard shortcut differences between it and Sublime.

It's a new editor though, I wouldn't be surprised if they added it back in a new version.

Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization

Answer (score 1):

To be clear by using pictures, you can create a `KEYBINDG` easily on `macOS` like following;

1- Press `SHIFT`+`COMMAND`+`P` and type `lower` then click `settings` icon[image]

2- Right click and the `Add binding`

[image]

3- `Press` the **desired key combination** and then press `ENTER`

[image]

4- Close the tab and then select an `UPPER CASE` text and press your key combination. Magically, it will be `upper case` :)