# Make selected block of text uppercase

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can I make a multi-line selection of text all capitals in *Visual Studio Code*?

In Visual Studio it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to do this.

The extension that exists that I have seen only do non-multi-line blocks.

*Note: The UI of VSCode has changed since this question was asked .*

Answer (score 757, accepted):

The question is about how to make <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> work in Visual Studio Code. Here is how to do it in *version 1.57.1* or above.

#### Steps:

1. Open Visual Studio Code.
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.
3. Type

   ```
   open keyboard shortcuts
   ```
4. Select

   > Open keyboard shortcuts (json)

An editor will appear with keybindings.json file.
Place the following JSON in there and save:

```json
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+u",
        "command": "editor.action.transformToUppercase",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+l",
        "command": "editor.action.transformToLowercase",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }
]
```

Now <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> will capitalise selected text, even if multi line. In the same way, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will make selected text lowercase.

These commands are built into VS Code and no extensions are required to make them work.

---

## Update August 2021

There is a UI to see and update keyboard shortcuts:

> *File-> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts*.

1. Find "Transform to Uppercase":

   [image]
2. Click the `+` icon.
3. In the popup, press the desired key combination and hit enter:

   [image]

Do the same for *lower case*.

---

#### Note

*In the new versions (eg 1.57.x) of VS Code, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is a shortcut for bulk selecting all selected text occurrences. So you can use another combination, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>* etc.

Comment: As others have said on Ubuntu 17.10 CTRL-SHIFT-U just gives you a `u` but CTRL-SHIFT-L works fine.  Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: I want a Toggle shortcut like PhpStorm instead of two separated shortcut: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/toggling-case.html

Comment: @MarkLawrence I had the same problem. I just picked a different letter (I used `Q`) and it works.

Comment: @MarkLawrence see this SO: https://superuser.com/questions/358749/how-to-disable-ctrlshiftu-in-ubuntu-linux

Comment: @MarkLawrence I ended up using `ctrl` + `alt` + `u` and `l`

Comment: I couldn't access the preferences JSON. It shows an aweful GUI with no obvious way to access the JSON file, then binded my shortcuts there.

Comment: THE UI HAS CHANGED SINCE THIS QUESTION WAS ASKED.

Answer (score 273):

Whenever you want to do something in VS Code and don't know how, it's a good idea to bring up the command palette with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on mac), and try typing in a keyword for you want. Oftentimes the command will show up there so you don't have to go searching the net for how to do something.

Highlight the text you want to uppercase.  Then hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the command palette.  Then start typing the word "uppercase", and you'll see the `Transform to Uppercase` command.  Click that and it will make your text uppercase.

Comment: Use option-x to bring up the command palette on OSX (VSCode v1.27). Even quicker if you're using the Emacs Friendly Keymap: highlight the text, then ^X^U to uppercase, or ^X^L to lowercase (where ^=ctrl).

Comment: I like this answer because it doesn't require a keybinding.

Comment: I think this answer is better if you just need the function for a moment.

Answer (score 70):

Creator of the [change-case](https://github.com/wmaurer/vscode-change-case) extension here. I've updated the extension to support spanning lines.

To map the upper case command to a keybinding (e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>), click *File -> Preferences -> Keyboard* shortcuts, and insert the following into the json config:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+t ctrl+u",
  "command": "extension.changeCase.upper",
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

EDIT:

With the November 2016 [(release notes)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates#_sublime-text-compatibility) update of *VSCode*, there is built-in support for converting to upper case and lower case via the commands `editor.action.transformToUppercase` and `editor.action.transformToLowercase`. These don't have default keybindings. They also work with multi-line blocks.

The [change-case](https://github.com/wmaurer/vscode-change-case) extension is still useful for other text transformations, e.g. camelCase, PascalCase, snake_case, kebab-case, etc.

Comment: When I set a key binding to "ctrl+t ctrl+u" it stops the "ctrl+t" binding from working. I'm not sure if this is a vscode bug, or if it is intended behavior.

Comment: @AlexMussell I believe this is the indented behaviour of VSCode

Answer (score 28):

Update on March 8, 2018 with Visual Studio Code 1.20.1 (mac)

It has been simplified quite a lot lately.
Very easy and straight forward now.

1. From "Code" -> "Preferences" -> "Keyboard shortcuts"
2. From the search box just search for "editor.action.transformTo", 
   You will see the screen like: 
   [image: screenshot of keyboard shortcuts setup dialog in Visual Studio Code (mac)]
3. Click the "plus" sign at the left of each item, 
   it will prompt dialog for your to [press] you desired key-bindings, 
   after it showing that on the screen, just hit [Enter] to save.

Comment: Actually this is the best answer -- the functions are already there, and we just need to change the shortcut keys. Others require too many changes.

Answer (score 22):

> **In Linux and Mac there are not default shortcuts**, so try to set your custom shortcut and be careful about don't choose a hotkey used (For example,
>    <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> is taken for uncomment)

1. *File-> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts*.
2. Type 'transfrom' in the search input to find transform shortcuts.
3. Edit your key combination.

In my case I have <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> for transform to uppercase and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for transform to lowercase

[image]

Just in case, for Mac instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> I used <kbd>⌘</kbd>

Comment: Valeu dêmáás :)

Answer (score 20):

## Change letter case in Visual Studio Code

### Updated answer

**Show All Commands:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

**and start typing** "*upper*" or "*lower*" whichever command is highlighted, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image]

**Note 1.** The next time you use the function, it is usually enough to type the first letter of "*upper*" or "*lower*" words.

**Note 2.** You can also assign your own shortcut to these functions as they currently don't have any by default:

[image]

---

[image]

### Original answer from 2017 (no longer valid for newer VSC versions)

To upper case: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

and to lower case: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

**Mnemonics**:

<kbd>**K**</kbd> like the **K**eyboard

<kbd>**U**</kbd> like the **U**pper case

<kbd>**L**</kbd> like the **L**ower case

Comment: Doesn't work. May you talk about VS, not VS-code.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, @AzrielBerger. This answer was correct in 2017, now VSC has removed the default keyboard shortcuts for these actions, but I have updated the answer to the current version.

Answer (score 12):

I think you can use

1. Select text
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
3. Enter `Transform to Uppercase`

Answer (score 9):

## Without defining keyboard shortcuts

1. Select the text you want capitalized
2. Open View->Command Palette (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
3. Start typing "Transform to uppercase" and select that option
4. Voila!

Answer (score 8):

At **Sep 19 2018**, these lines worked for me:

*File-> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts.*

An editor will appear with keybindings.json file. Place the following JSON in there and save.

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+u",
        "command": "editor.action.transformToUppercase",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+l",
        "command": "editor.action.transformToLowercase",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },

]
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm using the change-case extension and it works fine.
I defined the shortcuts:

```
{ 
  "key": "ctrl+shift+u", 
  "command": "extension.changeCase.upper", 
  "when": "editorTextFocus" 
},
{ 
  "key": "ctrl+u",
  "command": "extension.changeCase.lower", 
  "when": "editorTextFocus" 
},
```

Answer (score 3):

there is also a related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30265978/how-to-switch-text-case-in-visual-studio-code) about this where it states (Windows):

```
Command Palette: CTRL + SHIFT + p (Mac: CMD + SHIFT + p)
type >transform pick upper/lower case and press enter
```

What is pitty though is that on Notepad++ you are not forced to use the transform function to make simple things like uppercase and lowercase, a simple CTRL + SHIFT + U makes the job very good :)

Answer (score 2):

Standard keybinding for VS Code on macOS:

Selection to upper case <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
and to lower case: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

All key combinations can be opened with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (like **K**eyboard **S**ettings), where you can also search for specific key combinations.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Select the text to transform.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to selected the whole line

Open Show all commands.

Linux and Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, Mac: ⇧⌘P

Type in the command, e.g. lower, upper, title

Hit Enter

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac, in Visual Studio Code, its very easy to add a key binding to perform this action, it is not linked to a hotkey combo as a default though.

- In the menu bar, navigate to: Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts
- In the search bar that comes up, type: Uppercase
- A entry will come up called "Transform to Uppercase"
- Hover your mouse over that entry and click the plus sign just to the left of the words "Transform to Uppercase"
- In the box that comes up push the keys you want to bind that action to (Cmd +Shift + U is taken so I chose Ctrl + Shift + U) then press enter and you're good to go.

Note this is working at the time of this writing in May of 2021