# How to replace a string with its uppercase with NSRegularExpression in Swift?

Tags: regex, swift

I was trying to change `hello_world` to `helloWorld` by this snippet of code (Swift 3.0):

```
import Foundation

let oldLine = "hello_world"
let fullRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: oldLine.characters.count)
let newLine = NSMutableString(string: oldLine)

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(_)(\\w)", options: [])
regex.replaceMatches(in: newLine, options: [], range: fullRange, 
    withTemplate: "\\L$2")
```

The result was `newLine = "helloLworld"`

I used `"\\L$2"` as template because I saw this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20742304/5282792 saying `\L$2` is the pattern for the second group's uppercase in replacement template. But it didn't work in `NSRegularExpression`.

So can I replace a string with its uppercase with a replacement template pattern in `NSRegularExpression`.

Comment: SublimeText uses Boost regex that supports `\L` operator. Swift uses ICU, it does not support case chahging operators.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So `NSRegularExpression` supports nothing other than `$num` in replacement template?

Comment: A backslash is also a special char in ICU regex replacement patterns, see [*ICU User Guide: Replacement Text*](http://www.icu-project.org/userguide/regexp).

Comment: Are you set on using a RegEx for this? I could give you some code using methods on `String` that would do what you want nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to work with your case is subclassing `NSRegularExpression` and override `replacementString(for:in:offset:template:)` method.

```
class ToUpperRegex: NSRegularExpression {
    override func replacementString(for result: NSTextCheckingResult, in string: String, offset: Int, template templ: String) -> String {
        guard result.numberOfRanges > 2 else {
            return ""
        }
        let matchingString = (string as NSString).substring(with: result.rangeAt(2)) as String
        return matchingString.uppercased()
    }
}

let oldLine = "hello_world"
let fullRange = NSRange(0..<oldLine.utf16.count) //<-
let tuRegex = try! ToUpperRegex(pattern: "(_)(\\w)")
let newLine = tuRegex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: oldLine, range: fullRange, withTemplate: "")
print(newLine) //->helloWorld
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question pertaining regex, but might be of interest for readers not necessarily needing to use regex to perform this task (rather, using native Swift)

```
extension String {
    func camelCased(givenSeparators separators: [Character]) -> String {
        let charChunks = characters.split { separators.contains($0) }
        guard let firstChunk = charChunks.first else { return self }
        return String(firstChunk).lowercased() + charChunks.dropFirst()
            .map { String($0).onlyFirstCharacterUppercased }.joined()
    }

    // helper (uppercase first char, lowercase rest)
    var onlyFirstCharacterUppercased: String {
        let chars = characters
        guard let firstChar = chars.first else { return self }
        return String(firstChar).uppercased() + String(chars.dropFirst()).lowercased()
    }
}

/* Example usage */
let oldLine1 = "hello_world"
let oldLine2 = "fOo_baR BAX BaZ_fOX"

print(oldLine1.camelCased(givenSeparators: ["_"]))      // helloWorld
print(oldLine2.camelCased(givenSeparators: ["_", " "])) // fooBarBazBazFox
```