# Replace UPPERCASE with lowercase inside or between <> quotes or angle brackets

Tags: html, replace, uppercase, lowercase

Hello first all thanks for your help I want to replace UPPERCASE with lowercase inside or between <> quotes or angle brackets.

Sample: replace Capital to lower

```
<img src="/images/Cars/Icon/CompactCars-icon.PNG" />
```

becomes

```
<img src="/images/cars/icon/compactcars-icon.png" />
```

or

```
<a href="/Carsales/Buy-Buxury-suvs.html">
<a href="/carsales/buy-luxury-suvs.html">
```

or

`<HTML>` to `<html>`

Replace just between `<>`

But not replace nothing inside:

`<h2 class="article-title"><center>United States Cars For Sale</h2>`

as you can see `United States Car For Sale` are inside `<>` and I don't want to replace that.

Comment: Thanks I tried almost everything I found online: found in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742076/regex-replace-uppercase-with-lowercase-letters

Comment: What language are you using and in what context are you trying to do this?  I recommend that you read the article on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question to improve your chances of getting a good answer to your questions.

Comment: Sorry Nypan I'm not a Software Engineer like you I apologize for my low knowledge about this stuff, that is why I came here with the idea that someone smartest than me could help me to fix this problem, sorry you could not understand my question and thanks for your help.