# How do I use regex to replace continuous UPPER case to lower case? (But not replace the single upper characters)

Tags: regex

Text example,

> We will NOT let these Caravans, which are also made up of some very
>   bad thugs and gang members, into the U.S. Our Border is sacred, must
>   come in legally.

I want to replace `NOT` to `not`. But don't replace `We, Caravans, U.S. Our Border`.

I found this [Regex replace uppercase with lowercase letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742076/regex-replace-uppercase-with-lowercase-letters)

```
Find: (\w) Replace With: \L$1
```

This replaces all the upper cases.

PS: My reason for doing this is that I use a TTS to produce sounds. `NOT` will be pronounced to `N.O.T`. I just want it to be read as `not`. I don't want to replace too many things. Because reader will see the text, keeping original will be good.

Comment: post your attempts.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, My reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `\L` before a capture group turns it to lower case in whatever your environment is, sounds like all you need to do is to find occurrences of two or more upper-case characters: match

```
([A-Z]{2,})
```

and replace with

```
\L$1
```

If you only want full words to be replaced, then add word boundaries as well:

```
(\b[A-Z]{2,}\b)
```

(you may be able to omit the capture group and use `$&` instead of `$1`)

Answer (score 0):

Just in your posted question [Regex replace uppercase with lowercase letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742076/regex-replace-uppercase-with-lowercase-letters)

The second answer can solve your problem

find:

```
([A-Z]){2,n}
```

replace:

```
\L$1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd go with this:

```
(\b[A-Z]{2,}\b)
```

The `\b` is a word boundary, the `[A-Z]` is simply capital letters, and the `{2,}` is two or more.

https://regex101.com/r/qHmE1V/1

And in your replace `\L$1`